# Python code doesn't see data files after I packaged it with setuptools and installed with pip

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

I have packaged some python code with `setuptools`. The code uses a data file, but after installing the package with `pip`, the code cannot find the data file. What am I doing wrong?

---

Below are the file structure and file contents. The files may be found [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1K8XTwGzI6NONdH_JdZmNRPBpsDur5YUR). The python code `setup.py` is trying to use the `mesa/a.txt` data file. The code works fine if I don't package+pip it.

```
|
|- tm/
|  |- __init__.py
|  |- test2.py
|- mesa/
|  |- __init__.py
|  |- a.txt
|- MANIFEST.in
|- setup.py
```

`MANIFEST.in`:

```
include mesa/a.txt
```

`setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(name='bobab',
      version='0.1',
      py_modules=['tm.test2'],
      author_email='x@gmail.com',
      package_data = {
        'tm': ['mesa/a.txt']
        },
    )
```

`'mesa/a.txt`:

```
hello world!
```

`tm/test2.py`:

```
import os

def main():
    print 'hi' 
    print open(os.path.join('..', 'mesa', 'a.txt'), 'r').read() # print file content

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

I use the command `python setup.py sdist` to create the package. I use the following command to install the package:

```
unzip bobab-0.1.zip
cd bobab-0.1
python setup.py install
```

The package doesn't see the data file `mesa/a.txt`, as illustrated in the error message below:

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
>>> import tm.test2
>>> tm.test2.main()
hi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "tm/test2.py", line 5, in main
    print open(os.path.join('..', 'mesa', 'a.txt'), 'r').read()
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../mesa/a.txt'
```

I use Python 2.7.

---

Below are the packaging and installation logs. Interestingly, the packaging log mentions that the data file `mesa/a.txt` was added to the package, but the installation log doesn't mention the presence of it.

Packaging log:

```
C:\Users\Franck\Documents\GitHub\misc\src\test>python setu
p.py sdist
running sdist
running egg_info
creating bobab.egg-info
writing bobab.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to bobab.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to bobab.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing pbr to bobab.egg-info\pbr.json
writing manifest file 'bobab.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest file 'bobab.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'bobab.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
warning: sdist: standard file not found: should have one of README, README.rst,
README.txt

running check
warning: check: missing required meta-data: url

warning: check: missing meta-data: either (author and author_email) or (maintain
er and maintainer_email) must be supplied

creating bobab-0.1
creating bobab-0.1\bobab.egg-info
creating bobab-0.1\mesa
creating bobab-0.1\tm
copying files to bobab-0.1...
copying MANIFEST.in -> bobab-0.1
copying setup.py -> bobab-0.1
copying bobab.egg-info\PKG-INFO -> bobab-0.1\bobab.egg-info
copying bobab.egg-info\SOURCES.txt -> bobab-0.1\bobab.egg-info
copying bobab.egg-info\dependency_links.txt -> bobab-0.1\bobab.egg-info
copying bobab.egg-info\pbr.json -> bobab-0.1\bobab.egg-info
copying bobab.egg-info\top_level.txt -> bobab-0.1\bobab.egg-info
copying mesa\a.txt -> bobab-0.1\mesa
copying tm\__init__.py -> bobab-0.1\tm
copying tm\test2.py -> bobab-0.1\tm
Writing bobab-0.1\setup.cfg
creating 'dist\bobab-0.1.zip' and adding 'bobab-0.1' to it
adding 'bobab-0.1\MANIFEST.in'
adding 'bobab-0.1\PKG-INFO'
adding 'bobab-0.1\setup.cfg'
adding 'bobab-0.1\setup.py'
adding 'bobab-0.1\bobab.egg-info\dependency_links.txt'
adding 'bobab-0.1\bobab.egg-info\pbr.json'
adding 'bobab-0.1\bobab.egg-info\PKG-INFO'
adding 'bobab-0.1\bobab.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
adding 'bobab-0.1\bobab.egg-info\top_level.txt'
adding 'bobab-0.1\mesa\a.txt'
adding 'bobab-0.1\tm\test2.py'
adding 'bobab-0.1\tm\__init__.py'
removing 'bobab-0.1' (and everything under it)
```

Installation log:

```
(sedona) dernonco@ilcompn0:/mnt/ilcompn0d1/user/dernonco/temp/bobab-0.1$ python setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing bobab.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to bobab.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to bobab.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'bobab.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'bobab.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/tm
copying tm/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/tm
copying tm/test2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/tm
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/tm
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/tm/__init__.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/tm
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/tm/test2.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/tm
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/tm/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/tm/test2.py to test2.pyc
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying bobab.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying bobab.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying bobab.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying bobab.egg-info/pbr.json -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying bobab.egg-info/top_level.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
creating dist
creating 'dist/bobab-0.1-py2.7.egg' and adding 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg' to it
removing 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg' (and everything under it)
Processing bobab-0.1-py2.7.egg
Copying bobab-0.1-py2.7.egg to /mnt/ilcompn0d1/user/dernonco/pyenv/sedona/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Adding bobab 0.1 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /mnt/ilcompn0d1/user/dernonco/pyenv/sedona/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bobab-0.1-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for bobab==0.1
Finished processing dependencies for bobab==0.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several things should be adapted:

1. `MANIFEST.in` will be used only when you package source dists, so `python setup.py sdist` will include `mesa/a.txt` even with your current setup. This is not the case with binary distributions, neither `bdist_egg` nor `bdist_wheel` will read the `MANIFEST.in`.
2. `package_data` is usually used for non-python files placed inside the package, but `mesa` is not placed inside the `tm` dir, so the relative path is wrong. You can circumvent this by setting the dotted path:

   ```
   package_data={'tm': ['../mesa/a.txt']}
   ```

   However, if `mesa` is part of `tm` package, it makes sense to put it where it belongs.
3. `os.path.join('..', 'mesa', 'a.txt')` will resolve the path relative to current directory, so this line can find the file only when you're in the `tm` directory - after installing the package, it will be hardly the case. You need to resolve the path properly, for example against the `__file__` attribute:

   ```
   os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'mesa', 'a.txt')
   ```

Additional notes:

1. You can safely replace `py_modules=['tm.test2']` with `packages=['tm']` and don't need to care about updating `py_modules` when adding further modules to `tm` package.
2. `setuptools` offers a module named `pkg_resources` that offers useful management functions for non-python files installed via `package_data`. For example,

   ```
   open(os.path.join('..', 'mesa', 'a.txt'), 'r').read()
   ```

   could be replaced with

   ```
   pkg_resources.resource_string('tm', '../mesa/a.txt')
   ```

   Refer to [ResourceManager API](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#resourcemanager-api) section in the `setuptools` docs if you want to learn more.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer! That solved my issue and improved my understanding of how to use `setuptools`.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

when I'm working with files calling on other files in different folders i use this code at the top of the file.

```
from os.path import dirname, join, abspath
sys.path.insert(0, abspath(join(dirname(__file__), '..')))
```

and then

```
from file_name import value
```